# js: how to access a class defined inside require from the outside (accessibility issue)

Tags: javascript, class, requirejs, require

This question is bothering me for a while.
I'm trying to call a class from outside require (accessibility issue), my code looks like the above.

```
require(['foo'],
    (foo) => {
        class Bar {
            hello() {
                return "hello";
            }
        }
    });
bar = new Bar();
//uncaught ReferenceError: Chart is not defined
```

I've found one workaround, this is done by using window.Bar = class Bar...

```
require(['foo'],
    (foo) => {
        window.Bar = class Bar {
            hello() {
                return "hello";
            }
        }
    });
bar = new Bar();
//OK
```

However, this is not a convenient solution when it comes to converting it using Babel.

Do you know any other more correct way to export/define this class so that it could be called from an upper level?

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't. Instead, you'd write your full module code *inside* the callback:

```
require(['foo'], foo => {
    class Bar {
        hello() {
            return "hello";
        }
    }
    const bar = new Bar();
    // ...rest of code here...
});
```

That's the normal way Require-style modules are written. You don't write anything at the top-level of the script, it's all within the callback, not least so that Require can call it when appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

> correct way to export/define this class

When you want to "export" things, what you want to do is create a module. To do this, you use the `define` call, not `require`. You can then just return what you want exported. For instance:

```
define(['foo'], (foo) => {
  class Bar {
    hello() {
      return "hello";
    }
  };

  return Bar;
});
```

If this code is in a file named `bar.js` and you have your RequireJS configuration set properly so that RequireJS can *find it*, then you can do `require(["bar"], function (Bar) {...})` from somewhere else, or other modules can use it with:

```
define(["bar"], function (Bar) {
  const bar = new Bar();
  // do more stuff...
});
```

Both `require` and `define` load dependencies and execute their callback with the resolved dependencies, but only `define` actually *defines* modules. There's no notion of "exporting" with RequireJS unless you are in a module, which means you use `define`.